# Evaluate $\frac{1+\frac{1}{2^p}+\frac{1}{3^p}+\frac{1}{4^p}+...}{1-\frac{1}{2^p}+\frac{1}{3^p}-\frac{1}{4^p}+...}$ where $p>1$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Evaluate $\frac{1+\frac{1}{2^p}+\frac{1}{3^p}+\frac{1}{4^p}+...}{1-\frac{1}{2^p}+\frac{1}{3^p}-\frac{1}{4^p}+...}$ where $p>1$.

Attempt: Observe that $B=\frac{1}{2^p}+\frac{1}{4^p}+...=\frac{1}{2^p}(1+\frac{1}{2^p}+\frac{1}{3^p}+\frac{1}{4^p}+...)=\frac{1}{2^p}(A+B)$. Rearrage top and bottom should give results. Are there any alternative solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Not really an alternative but we can put this problem in a bigger context. Note that the nominator is nothing more that $\zeta(p)$, the Riemann Zeta Function, and the denominator is given by $\eta(p)$, the Dirichlet Eta Function. So we are looking for $\frac{\zeta(p)}{\eta(p)}$.

Those two are related by

> $$\eta(p)~=~(1-2^{1-p})\zeta(p)$$

As one can show precisely in the same way you have. Another way of approaching is via the following chain of equalities

\begin{align*}
\eta(p)=\sum_{n\geqslant1}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^p}&=\sum_{n\geqslant1}\frac1{n^p}-2\sum_{n\geqslant1}\frac1{(2n)^p}\\
&=\sum_{n\geqslant1}\frac1{n^p}-\frac1{2^{p-1}}\sum_{n\geqslant1}\frac1{n^p}\\
&=\zeta(p)-2^{1-p}\zeta(p)=(1-2^{1-p})\zeta(p)
\end{align*}

Note that we are only allowed to rearrange the series when it converges absolutely, which means in this case that $p>1$. However, we obtain

> $$\therefore~\frac{\zeta(p)}{\eta(p)}=\frac{\zeta(p)}{(1-2^{1-p})\zeta(p)}=\frac{2^p}{2^p-2}$$

I suppose any other way of attempting to solve this task would be unnecessary complicated.